# why does port Forwarding dont open my port

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, kvm-virtualization

i am struggling with port forwarding and virtualization, i have come quite far and could open and forward a port (9867) to my vm after this tutorial: https://aboullaite.me/kvm-qemo-forward-ports-with-iptables/

here my iptables:

```
root@s1 ~/.ssh # iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4445 packets, 245K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    5   220 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9888 to:192.168.122.191:2302
    9   452 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9867 to:192.168.122.192:22

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4377 packets, 237K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 35 packets, 2529 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 41 packets, 2793 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     224.0.0.0/24
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255
   34  1768 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
   85  5512 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.111.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
   13  1608 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
```

with the port 9867 it works great, here my nmap output:

```
root@kali:~# nmap <my Server> -p 9867
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-07-16 12:58 EDT
Nmap scan report for <my Server> (<my Server IP>)
Host is up (0.020s latency).
rDNS record for <my Server IP>: static.<my Server IP>.clients.your-server.de

PORT     STATE SERVICE
9867/tcp open  unknown
```

but my port 9888 is closed:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
9888/tcp closed cyborg-systems
```

can anyone tell me why it's not open? I followed the instructions above for both.

I would be very happy about an answer... :)

Comment: Is anything on the VM listening to this port?

Comment: @vidarlo thank you very much for your reply, my vm hase use more ports than i thought... -> i make an answere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after days of searching, i found out that my server running in the windows VM needed more ports than i released - i released all the ones i found in the docu... -.

If you start with KVM VM´s and want to connect to VM´s from the internet, then configure a bridged network in which you combine your network interface. After that the VM´s will be managed as devices in a NAT network.

Then these instructions can be used to realize the port forwarding from the Internet to the port of the Vm:

```
https://aboullaite.me/kvm-qemo-forward-ports-with-iptables/
```

The VM is created in this way:

```
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-kvm-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server/
```

The ports I checked with nmap were not used by my server running in my Vm, so it looked like the ports were closed. But if you follow the instructions, it works, at least for Ubuntu 16.04.